# enterprise iphone application: how user can install it?

Tags: ios, enterprise

I want create iPhone application, that must not published in iTunes. 
I found that exist [opportunity](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) to develop enterprise application

I can't found information, what users must to do to install such application. Is this application available for any user, or user must to install or bought something else?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you belong from one of these countries, You can opt for apple's Volume Purchase Plan.

**Countries:**
Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, New Zealand, Spain, United Kingdom, and United States.

Here is [the link to go for](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/)

Enjoy:)